# How can I change the rotation angle of numpad controls in blender?

Tags: 3d-view

I just have a quick question
How can I change the rotation angle of my numpad controls when in the viewport?
Numpad 2, 4, 6, and 8 rotate the viewport down, left, right, and up, respectively.
But I think it goes in 15-degree steps.
How can I tweak this to go at other angles other than 15?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the size of those increments in Preferences (*Edit* → *Preferences*), *Navigation* → *Orbit and pan* ⇾ *Rotation angle*.

[image]